# Excluding properties from a viewmodel

Tags: asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0

I have a viewmodel that contains a CustomerModel e.g.

```
 public class MyAccountViewModel
{
    public CustomerModel Customer { get; set; }
    public LoginModel Login { get; set; }
    public ICollection<AuthenticationClientData> Clients { get; set; }
    public bool HasLocalPassword { get; set; }
    public LocalPasswordModel Password { get; set; }
}

  [DataContract]
public class CustomerModel
{
    [DataMember]
    public Guid CustomerBusinessId { get; set; }

    [DataMember(IsRequired = true)]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "First Name is required")]
    [Display(Name = "First Name")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [DataMember(IsRequired = true)]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Last Name is required")]
    [Display(Name = "Last Name")]
    public string LastName { get; set; }


    [DataMember]
    public string FullName
    {
        get { return string.Format("{0} {1}", FirstName, LastName); }
    }

    [DataMember]
    public string Identity { get; set; }

    [DataMember(IsRequired = true)]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Email is required")]
    public string Email { get; set; }


    [DataMember]
    [Display(Name = "Birth Date")]
    public DateTime? BirthDate { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string Mobile { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string Phone { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string Twitter { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    [Display(Name = "Facebook")]
    public string FaceBook { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string WebSite { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string Blog { get; set; }

}
```

My CustomerModel object contains a property "CustomerBusinessId" is it possible for my viewmodel to exclude this property so I am only returning the required fields to the view?

Comment: Have you considered creating a `CustomerViewModel` that just contains the properties that you need?

Comment: Is there any reason you don't want to pass it to your view? From a performance point of view, it doesn't make a difference, and in your view you could just ignore the field.

Comment: How and where are you using this CustomerBusinessId? Can you share that code also?

Comment: CustomerBusinessId is just one example of the properties I dont want to display or have to worry about for a form being posted. I was hoping to be able to use the CustomerModel once as the project is used in multiple projects. I can make another vm with the properties I was just hoping to reuse the model